# How to select appropriate subtype if I know just paret type ID?

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following trouble: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa224923.howmanystoomanyfigure_01(l=en-us,v=sql.80).gif

In this image I saw model of realization supertype and subtype relationship.

**Question is**: if I know VehicleID and how to know exactly which kind of vehicle is it? The way I so is to write select to each table ( but it looks really ugly).
Or maybe to write help table to know which type is it, but I'm not sure. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what results you are trying to get? For example, is it just all columns about cars? Or are you trying to get all columns about anything in the same results.

Comment: @Steve E, I need to select all columns of subtype. I know supertype id, I don't know how to know which subtype has that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vehicles table has a 'type' column. This would have values in such as 'truck', 'car', 'motorcycle' and tells your code which table to query for the rest of the data.

Because the columns in the sub tables are different. I would recommend looking up the type in the Vehicles table before using a second query to get the type specific data.